# Greasemonkey - Including Javascript file with ?Variables - for NOcache

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am including a Javascript file in greasemonkey / tampermonkey like this

```
// @require  https://ajax.nemach.jeh.js
```

**The problem is the javascript gets cached**, also hitting shift+f5 doesn't empty cache. Out of security concerns i can neither access the caching nor prevent it in browsers.

reloading is no option and doesn't work neither, if someone needs that:

```
location.reload(true);
```

Back 2my question. I would like to do something like this:

```
var non_c_js = "https://ajax.nemach.jeh.js"+ Math.random()*1000;
// @require  non_c_js
```

Can this be achieved somehow in GM/TM?

Thanks for time and wisdom

Comment: do you need this to test your script ? because basically it should be the same file allways :)

Comment: You could just execute a direct AJAX call inside your script instead of defining it as a dependency.

Comment: if you just need to do this while programming your script to see some changes... you could try to open your browser in incognito mode. This should prevent the browser from caching the script.

Comment: @sirko do you hava a working small example? I could also add a script tag with variables to the head but i thought maybe GM has something built in for that purpose ??

Comment: @dzwa thanks, this might help others. the script will be updated unregularly because of chances of the underlaid website and that changing domstructure.

Comment: @Email http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest